# Bijection map from a set of subgroup to another set of subgroup under some condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $U \leq G$ such that $G = NU$. Then there exists a bijection, preserving inclusion, from the set of subgroups $X$ satisfying $U ≤ X ≤ G$ to the set of $U-$invariant subgroups $Y$ satisfying $U \cap N ≤ Y ≤ N$.

This is a problem from Kurzweil-Stellmacher book. I dont know how to do it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you aware that $NU/N\cong N/(N\cap U)$?

Comment: Yes i did! How it will help?

Comment: Just writing an answer now then...

Comment: Hmm. I have just realised that what I thought doesn't quite work. Are you sure you have copied it our correctly? Are you sure $U$ isn't meant to be normal?...(as opposed to $N$?)

Comment: Yes I am sure. Thank you for your time.

Comment: (On a side note - I wrote the isomorphism above incorrectly. It should be $NU/N\cong U/(N\cap U)$.)

Comment: Okay, I will tell you my attempted solution and how you might amend it. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to work it out. So, there exists a bijection between the set of subgroup $X$ satisfying $N\leq X\leq G$ to the set of $N$-invariant subgroups satisfying $U\cap N\leq Y\leq U$. This is simply because of the above isomorphism, and you should work out why this is before going further. Drawing the inclusions gives you a square, and drawing the $X$s and $Y$s I have just described gives you two sides of the square. This question asks you about the *other two sides* of the square.

Comment: I believe the way to attack the problem will be to think of the elements of $X$ where $U\leq X\leq NU$ as elements $xu$ where $x\in N$, $u\in U$ then consider the map $xu\mapsto x$. This is well-defined, but I am not convinced that the elements $x$ of $N$ form a subgroup. This therefore needs some work! But anyway, I think this gives you a map from a subgroup $X$ to a subgroup $Y$, and it works for every subgroup $X$. Then prove that every $Y$ is mapped onto in this way to complete the proof.

Comment: @j.p. $N$ is assumed to be normal in $G$ here too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you should use **Dedekind's Lemma**:

Let $U$ and $V$ be subgroups of a group $G$ and let $U \subseteq X \subseteq G$, with $X$ also a subgroup. Then $U(V \cap X)=UV \cap X$.

Note that $UV$ here is just a **subset** of $G$, not necessarily a **subgroup**! Anyway, in your case define a map $\phi$ from the set {$X$: $X$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $U \subseteq X \subseteq G$} to the set {$Y$: $Y$ is a $U$-invariant subgroup of $N$ with $N \cap U \subseteq Y \subseteq N$} by $\phi:X \mapsto X \cap N$. Observe that $\phi$ is well-defined by the normality of $N$. The injectivity of this map can be proved with Dedekind's Lemma. For the surjectivity look at an $X=YU$, of which you have to show it is a subgroup (remember $Y$ was $U$-invariant!) and again apply the lemma.